# how to complete this program studycase?

Tags: java

I got the project assignment in one of the courses and I was confused to finish it. Can you help me to complete this program ?

This is the Study Case.

Make a program to rent hotel room bookings!
Terms:
-Types of Rooms (President Suite, VVIP, Deluxe, Superior)
-Room rates (IDR 1,500,000, - IDR 1,000,000 IDR 800,000 IDR 500,000)
-If staying more than 3 nights, there is a 15% discount
-If the member there is an additional discount of 10%

Input:
-No KTP
-Name
-E-mail
-Gender
-Address
-Phone number
-Type of room
-Length of stay

Output:
-No KTP
-Name
-E-mail
-Gender
-Address
-Phone number
-Type of room
-Room price
-Length of stay
-Discount
-Total pay

Comment: If you're expecting somebody to write the code for you, we don't do that here sorry! First have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: .. and this: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), where it says "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score -1):

I would throw in something here; maybe you can work on top of that. Apparently, the only output values you need to work on are:

- Room Price
- Discount
- Total Pay

That shall simplify the problem a lot. Next up, how to determine Room Price? It seems that flat Room Price is dependent on type of room. Since each type of room has its specific price tag, maybe some data structure in Java can help with that.

Next up, Discount seems to be determined by length of stay. You already have length of stay as input, so figuring out Discount should be straightforward.

Finally, Total Pay seems to be determined by Room Price and Discount. At this point, you shall already have Room Price and length-of-stay discount available. Don’t forget there is also a membership discount, but you have to figure out how to determine membership status.

Comment: thank you for the answer. by the way can you help me to make a sample script program ?

Comment: I tried to be helpful, despite going against the normal practice here. But you asking for further spoon-feeding truly disappointed me.